Getting the length of MySQL2 array in TS
I have a query that gets executed. It grabs the records that are currently being logged in. Depending on how many devices, i'd like it to do certain things. However when I try to use
.length it throws this Property 'length' does not exist on type 'QueryResult'. Property 'length' does not exist on type 'OkPacket'.ts(2339) While it does still give me the length, I want to know if there are other ways to do it.
const findLoggedInDevices =
    "SELECT lg.device_id, u.username FROM log_history as lg INNER JOIN users as u on u.id = lg.uid WHERE is_logged_in = 1 AND u.id = ?";
  const [devices] = await db.execute(findLoggedInDevices, [data.uid]);
  const numberOfDevicesFound = devices.length;

Do I need to Have a seperate count query or is there something else I can do?
The response looks like this :
[
    {
        "device_id": "ssf",
        "username": "user2"
    },
    {
        "device_id": "sds",
        "username": "user2"
    },
    {
        "device_id": "ss",
        "username": "user2"
    }
]

